# MediaWiki: System Message for Search Results based on User Type

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

The default system message you get as a user when your MediaWiki search found no result is "Create the page "{whatever search term you entered}" on this wiki.

Now, I know how to modify the system message (for search results page) to my liking. But I want it in a way such that when Admins are logged in, I still see the "Create the page..." link, but when I'm logged in as a normal user, I need the link hidden or gone.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

System message `MediaWiki:noexactmatch-nocreate` should automatically be used if the user does not have the right to create articles, so it sounds like your anonymous users do have that right.  Here's how to stop them:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_page_creation